# "bitbake -g" vs. RDEPENDS

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, depends

I wonder how *bitbake -g* is implemented.
Probably it searches all recipes for *DEPENDS=...* occurrence, perhaps much more.
How to get dependency graph however that one reflecting *RDEPENDS=...* relations?

Answer (score 6):

`bitbake -g` generates both the `DEPENDS` and the `RDEPENDS` graphs.

Run, e.g. `bitbake -g -u depexp <target>` and the the Dependency Explorer UI (`depexp`)
will display a package menu in the left-hand pane with *Runtime Depends* and *Build Depends*
of the selected package displayed in sub-panes on the right.

If you simply run `bitbake -g <target>` to generate graphviz `.dot` files,
then the output `pn-depends.dot` graphs the buildtime dependencies and `package-depends.dot` graphs the runtime dependencies.
See *1.5.2.3. Generating Dependency Graphs* in [the manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html)

Comment: Warning on depexp UI though: the output was misleading for runtime dependencies (if I recall correctly) and because of that 'depexp' was replaced in the last release with 'taskexp': it only shows dependencies between the various tasks but does that much better than the old UI.